# How to check whether each USB3 port has a dedicated USB3 bus?

Tags: usb, usb-3, camera, bus

I am trying to setup multiple cameras. I want to know if my PC can handle the bandwidth of additional cameras. Currently, two cameras work fine but I want to be sure that it can handle also two extra ones before I buy them, which is why I need to check the USB3 connection.

I am using an "XMG P870DM2_DM3" motherboard, Windows 10 and Ubunto 16.04.

Comment: What kind of cameras are you using? Do you know what kind of bandwidth does each one need? Please post explicit URL links to your devices/motherboards.

Comment: Also, did you check other posts here, like this, https://superuser.com/q/497933/620011